# "Undefined symbols" linker error with simple template class

Tags: c++, templates, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Been away from C++ for a few years and am getting a linker error from the following code:

Gene.h

```
#ifndef GENE_H_INCLUDED
#define GENE_H_INCLUDED

template <typename T>
class Gene {
    public:
    T getValue();
    void setValue(T value);
    void setRange(T min, T max);

    private:
    T value;
    T minValue;
    T maxValue;
};

#endif // GENE_H_INCLUDED
```

Gene.cpp

```
#include "Gene.h"

template <typename T>
T Gene<T>::getValue() {
    return this->value;
}

template <typename T>
void Gene<T>::setValue(T value) {
    if(value >= this->minValue && value <= this->minValue) {
        this->value = value;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Gene<T>::setRange(T min, T max) {
    this->minValue = min;
    this->maxValue = max;
}
```

Using Code::Blocks and GCC if it matters to anyone. Also, clearly porting some GA stuff to C++ for fun and practice.

Comment: Exact error messages would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The template definition (the cpp file in your code) has to be included prior to instantiating a given template class, so you either have to include function definitions in the header, or #include the cpp file prior to using the class (or do explicit instantiations if you have a limited number of them).

Comment: Thanks! I must have learned that at one point. Maybe now it will stick :D

Comment: Or just implement the whole template in the header file. See the related question [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 5):

Including the cpp file containing the implementations of the template class functions works.  However, IMHO, this is weird and awkward.  There must surely be a slicker way of doing this?

If you have only a few different instances to create, and know them beforehand, then you can use "explicit instantiation"

This works something like this:

At the top of gene.cpp add the following lines

```
template class Gene<int>;
template class Gene<float>;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `if(value >= this->minValue && value <= this->minValue)` the second `minValue` should be `maxValue`, no?

Echo what Sean said: What's the error message?  You've defined and declared the functions, but you've not used them in anything anywhere, nor do I see an error (besides the typo).

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR

It seems that you need an **Explicit Instantiation** i.e. to *actually create the class*. Since template classes are just "*instructions*" on how to create a class you actually need to tell the compiler to create the class. Otherwise the linker won't find anything when it goes looking.

## The thorough explanation

When compiling your code g++ goes through a number of steps the problem you're seeing occurs in the *Linking* step. Template classes define how classes "*should*" be created, they're literally templates. During compile time g++ compiles each cpp file individually so the compiler sees your template on how to create a class but no instructions on what "classes" to create. Therefore ignores it. Later during the linking step the g++ attempts to link the file containing the class (the one that doesn't exist) and fails to find it ultimately returning an error.

To remedy this you actually need to "*explicitly instantiate*" the class by adding the following lines to Gene.cpp **after** the definition of the class

```
template class Gene<whatever_type_u_wanna_use_t>;int
```

Check out these [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) I found them to be super helpful.