# How to build a library while link to a testing executable in the same project using cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build a project that contains several user-defined libraries and a testing executables to test the libraries using cmake on Ubuntu. The structure of the project is as follow:

```
rootdir
|-- lib1
|   |-- include/lib1.h
|   |-- src/lib1.cpp
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- test
|   |-- test_lib1.cpp
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|---CMakeLists.txt
```

the **rootdir/test/test.cpp** has included the **rootdir/lib1/include/lib1.h**

the **rootdir/lib1/src/lib1.cpp** has included the **rootdir/lib1/include/lib1.h**

rootdir/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(mylib)

add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

rootdir/lib1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(lib1)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_library(lib1 SHARED src/lib1.cpp)
```

rootdir/test/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(test)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib1/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib1)

add_executable(test_lib1 test_lib1.cpp)
target_link_libraries (test_lib1 lib1)
```

The question is that I get "**undefined reference to...**" the functions defined in **lib1**.

Since I can find the **liblib1.so** in ***build/lib1/*** and get no error building the **lib1** library, I guess that the **lib1** library is built successfully.

One more strange thing is that I get "**undefined reference to...**" only those functions implemented in **lib1.cpp**. The simple functions implemented in **lib1.h** will not trigger the "**undefined reference to...**" error.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

---EDIT---

I followed the suggestion and put *add_subdirectory(lib1)* in front of *add_subdirectory(test)* in the root **CMakeLists.txt**. However, the same problem is still there.

---EDIT---

This is my project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/082oyglyjj46438/recognition.tar.gz?dl=0.

It is slightly different from the original problem since it links to an external library PCL. But the architecture is mostly the same.

Comment: I do not put the `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)` or the `project(test)` part in the testing application. I make it part of the root project.

Comment: Put `add_subdirectory(test)` after `add_subdirectory(lib1)` in the root CMakeLists.txt and get rid of `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)` and `project(lib1)`

Comment: I follow your suggest: 1) remove cmake_minimum_required() and project() in test/CMakeLists.txt and lib1/CMakeLists.txt. 2)put add_subdirectory(test) after add_subdirectory(lib1). However, the exact same problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...answer my own question.

The problem did not come from the CMakeLists.txt. Actually it is because the class is templated. A templated class just can't compile into a shared or static library.[see Ref.]

Here are three possible solutions

1. Compile your main program with all the class definition .cpps
2. Move the class definition into the header file, which contains the class declaration.
3. *****Instantiate the template***

If the templated types are limited. You can instantiate the template in the end of the class definition .cpps.

For example, suppose that your class is templated as follow:

```
template<T>
class myClass
{
    //class definitions
}
```

, and you know that the templated type ***T*** can only be *float* or *int*. Then just add the following to the lib1.cpp:

```
template class myclass<int>;
template class myclass<float>;
```

---

Ref.

[C++ Shared Library with Templates: Undefined symbols error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022623/c-shared-library-with-templates-undefined-symbols-error)

[Compile header-only template library into a shared library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349129/compile-header-only-template-library-into-a-shared-library)

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html#Template-Instantiation

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not linking correctly with the created library because you're adding the test subdirectory before adding the lib1 one. Anyway, try with these CMakeLists.txt

**rootdir/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(mylib)

SET(MYLIB_LIB_OUT_PATH ${mylib_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
SET(MYLIB_BIN_OUT_PATH ${mylib_SOURCE_DIR}/test/bin)

add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

**rootdir/lib1/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(lib1)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${MYLIB_LIB_OUT_PATH})

add_library(mylib SHARED src/lib1.cpp)
```

**rootdir/test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(test)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib1/include)
link_directories(${MYLIB_LIB_OUT_PATH})

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${MYLIB_BIN_OUT_PATH})

add_executable(test_lib1 test_lib1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_lib1 mylib)
```

I hope it works! ;)

Comment: I tried your solution as well as drescherjm's comment in the original post but still got the exact same problem.

Comment: Have you tried my code? It's different from yours one

Comment: Yes, I just copy and paste your CMakeLists.txt and modify some of the file names and folder names. This is my project : https://www.dropbox.com/s/082oyglyjj46438/recognition.tar.gz?dl=0. It is slightly different from the original problem since it links to an external library PCL. But the architecture is mostly the same.