# Is there a dlib library port for java?

Tags: java, dlib

I'm actually using OpenCV for face detection, but after watching this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsK0hzcEyHI , I've noticed that [dlib](http://blog.dlib.net/) is much more accurate, and even in my tests,  gives a lot of fale positives (but doesn't miss any face), does anyone know how to use dlib within a Java web application (not android) ? [I've already found a port to Android](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android), but I don't thinkk it's possible to use it with in a java web application.
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used dlib myself, and yes it is a very advanced and precise library. There is no port in Java as far as I know. But you can always **have it compiled to a shared library** (.so in linux or .dll in Windows), and then use that inside your Java code.

More on [using a dll](http://blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/) or [using an so](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp) in java

There is also an option to use the [C++ library directly within Java](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077513/learn-java/java-tip-17--integrating-java-with-c--.html), using proxies. You might want to look into that.

**Edit :** As per @evgeniy's comment, most of dlib is header-only templates. You will not be able to use those if you export dlib directly as a shared library. What you might want to do instead is to expose whatever APIs you need, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349129/compile-header-only-template-library-into-a-shared-library)

**Edit 2 :** As @davis-king's pointed out, you may want to look into using swig and cmake as is done in the mitie/dlib Java api : [See here.](http://blog.dlib.net/2014/10/mitie-v03-released-now-with-java-and-r.html)

Comment: this will not help. most of dlib is header-based and not contained in shared library

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure that is irrelevant, as even then the APIs relevant to the OP can easily be exposed THEN compiled into a shared lib. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349129/compile-header-only-template-library-into-a-shared-library

Comment: yes, you are right. the only thing I was trying to say, that dlib itself can be compiled as a shared library, but it will be impossible to use libdlib.so(.dll) as-is in java because all face detection functions are template-based and do not exist in libdlib.so. and yes, its possible to build some new library with dlib code inside and then use it in java

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for Android: https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android

Otherwise, this https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/49 looks like the most promising but still opened at the moment.