# How i detect particular object from face and add my image in real time?

Tags: java, android, opencv, opengl-es

I tried to search for this concepts. I wanna make such like change Lip color or change eye retina color using OpenCV on realtime camera open-gles view. what are the should i follow ? and how i use in my app via native library? please suggest ...sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 steps:

- Detect the lip and eye areas
- Change the color

The first step is solved by using [Dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib). This is currently available for c++ and python but you can use in java by this suggestion [dlib in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551998/is-there-a-dlib-library-port-for-java)

Note: dlib just gives you the area of eyes, in order to detect eye retina, you need to proceed further. For instance we could detect the darker area which is supposed to be retina.

landmark output

[image: landmark output]

Comment: Can you please split your thing how to do this thing using dlib