# How do Generics in C# provide source code protection

Tags: c#, generics

I am reading the book "CLR Via C#" and in the Generics chapter is said:

> **Source code protecton**
>
> The developer using a generic algorithm doesn't need to have access to the algorithm's source code. With C++ templates or Java's generics, however, the algorithm's source code must be available to the developer who is using the algorithm.

Can anyone explain what exactly is meant by this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, Generic classes are distributed in compiled form, unlike C++, where templates need to be distributed in full source code. So you do not need to distribute the C# source code of a library that contains generic classes.

This does not prevent the Receiver of your class from disassembling it though (as it is compiled to IL which can be rather easily decompiled again). To really protect the code, additional methods, such as obfuscation are required.

Behind the scene: This distribution in compiled form is the reason why C# generics and C++ templates also differ in the way they need to be written. C# generic classes and their methods need to be fully defined at the time of compilation, and any error in the definition of the generic class or their methods or any operation on a template parameter which cannot be deduced at compile time will directly produce a compile error. In C++ the template is only compiled at the time of usage and only the methods actually used are compiled. If you have an undefined operation or even a syntactical error in a template definition, you will only see the error when that function is actually instantiated and used.

Comment: [I think I learned something today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022623/c-shared-library-with-templates-undefined-symbols-error).

Comment: Right, that question answers why C++ needs the full source code.

Comment: @CodeCaster- Thanks for the link. I also learned something today. :)