# Linker error 'unresolved external symbol' : working with templates

Tags: c++, templates, qt4, visual-c++, linker-errors

I have a template based class [Allotter.h & Allotter.cpp]:

```
template <typename allotType> class Allotter {
public:
 Allotter();
 quint32 getAllotment(allotType*);
 bool removeAllotment(quint32, int auto_destruct = 0);

private:
 QVector<QPair<quint32, allotType*>> indexReg;
 int init_topIndex;
};
```

and it's usage is shown as [ActiveListener.h & ActiveListener.cpp]:

```
class ActiveListener: public QObject {
 Q_OBJECT

public:
 ActiveListener();

private slots:
    void processConnections();
    void readFromSocket(int);

private:
 QTcpServer* rootServer;
 QSignalMapper* signalGate;
 Allotter<QTcpSocket> TcpAllotter;
};
```

I am not showing the complete definitions, since it doesn't really matter. The problem is when I compile, all files compile properly. The files are in a VC++ project. Earlier when I did not use a template-based approach for `Allotter`, everything was compiling and linking fine. But now, I get this error:

```
1>ActiveListener.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Allotter<class QTcpSocket>::Allotter<class QTcpSocket>(void)" (??0?$Allotter@VQTcpSocket@@@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall ActiveListener::ActiveListener(void)" (??0ActiveListener@@QAE@XZ)
1>ActiveListener.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned int __thiscall Allotter<class QTcpSocket>::getAllotment(class QTcpSocket *)" (?getAllotment@?$Allotter@VQTcpSocket@@@@QAEIPAVQTcpSocket@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall ActiveListener::processConnections(void)" (?processConnections@ActiveListener@@AAEXXZ)
```

The surprising thing is, that the constructor, `ActiveListener::ActiveListener()` does not make any reference at all `Allotter<QTcpSocket>::Allotter()`. The second reference however does exist. But I don't understand why the linker isn't able to resolve this external symbol.

The build output just before the errors appear is:

```
1>Moc'ing ActiveListener.h...
1>Compiling...
1>stdafx.cpp
1>Compiling...
1>ActiveListener.cpp
1>Allotter.cpp
1>moc_ActiveListener.cpp
1>main.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Linking...
```

I don't understand if any of this is relevant, mostly because all this used to work perfectly before. It's just that after I use templates a problem is caused.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you all for the amount of help you've provided. I did a bit of research my self and have found somewhat a solution for the same issue: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13

I'm putting it here for others who happen to stumble here looking for solutions to similar problems.

Thanks again :D

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Undefined symbols" linker error with simple template class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999358/undefined-symbols-linker-error-with-simple-template-class)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot split templates into .h and .cpp files - you need to put the complete code for the template in the .h file.

Comment: @Charles:`export` works in real life (with the Comeau compiler).

Comment: thanks a lot for that :D
Could you just enlighten me as to why that happens? I'm assuming that whenever the compiler needs a specific class from a template i.e. MyClass<int> from MyClass<typename classType>, it needs to have the source code to generate the required class.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. All template definitions that are *parametrized* have to go into the .h file. Template definitions that is *not parametrized* (i.e. explicitly specialized templates) should be treated as "ordinary" code, meaning that classes are defined in .h files, while functions and obects are only *declared* in .h files and defined in .cpp files.

Comment: @Jerry the Comeau compiler ist unreal :-) Besides, `export` didn't make it into c++0x and probably never will.

Comment: @drhirsch:  `export` is part of the current C++ standard, and it has not been removed or deprecated (yet) from C++0x.  In addition, Comeau is not the only compiler that supports it; the Intel C++ Compiler for Linux also supports it.

Comment: FYI export has just been dropped from C++0x

Comment: This answer saved me a TON of time and hours of frustration. It seems that some compilers deal with this better than others... I found that my templates in the cpp file compiled fine on GCC but choked on MSVC compiler. =/

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking it is considered best practice to write your template code entirely inside header files. There is an important technical reason for this: when you instantiate a template, the C++ compiler needs to generate code from that template that is specific to the template parameters that you have specified. If your template code is placed entirely in your headers, this is done for you automatically.

It *is* definitely possible to write template code the way that you have, with the implementation placed in cpp files. If you do this, however, you are required to explicitly instantiate the template instance that you intend to use.

In your case, you need to add the following line to a .cpp file in your project:

```
template class Allotter<QTcpSocket>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't place template implementation in .cpp files, it is considered a good practice to use .inl files for the template implementation and include them from the template headers.