# Problem using templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I am using templates for the first time in C++ and running into a problem when I try to compile.  Basically trying to create my own basic ArrayList of sorts:

The .hpp:

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_HPP_
#define ARRAYLIST_HPP_

template <class T>
class ArrayList
{
    private:
        int current, top ;
        T * al ;

    public:
        ArrayList() ;   // default constructor is the only one
};

#endif /* ARRAYLIST_HPP_ */
```

The .cpp:

```
#include "ArrayList.hpp"

using namespace std ;

//template <class T>
//void memoryAllocator( T * p, int * n ) ; // private helper functions headers

template <class T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList()
{
    current = 0 ;
    top = 10 ;
    al = new T[top] ;
}
```

The main:

```
#include "ArrayList.hpp"

int main()
{
    ArrayList<int> test ;
}
```

When I try to build without the main it compiles fine, however, as soon as I try to use it in the main I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ArrayList<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::ArrayList()", referenced from:
      _main in Website.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [APProject2] Error 1
```

Any thoughts as to what might be the problem would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template operator linker error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007251/template-operator-linker-error)

Comment: this is asked a lot. Try search this site for "[c++] [template] linker".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the implementation in the .hpp file. The compiler needs to know T at compile time to generate the specialization.

Comment: In your main, you are instantiating ArrayList<int>. ArrayList.cpp doesn't have any specific type for T, so the compiler can't do anything with it. It needs a type. So if you put your .cpp implementation in the .hpp, and include the .hpp in your main, the compiler will instantiate an ArrayList<int> for you. Think of templates as, well, templates, or incomplete code that need extra information (types) in order to be compiled. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yah, a bit more sense indeed!  Thanks!
However, is it not possible to still maintain a separate .hpp and .cpp file for the declarations and the implementations?  Or do all the implementations for each method/constructor that uses a generic type have to be in the header file?

Comment: No, you can't put any code that uses the template parameters in a plain .cpp (well, you can, but it won't compile anything). Some people put the implementations in a .icpp, which is then included at the bottom of the .hpp, but this is just to keep the "declarations" in separate files. It can be useful if the implementaitons are lengthy and difficult for a huma to read. But as far as the compiler is concerned, it is the same, because the preprocessor will essentially merge the two files. If you look at the STL or Boost, you'll see that most libraries are 100% header files.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks!

P.s. one last quick question, since I already have your attention and all... :)

How do I do the following from Java in c++?

test.add( new SomeClassName( "stuff" ) ) ;

I know I can do:

SomeClassName temp( "stuff" ) ;

test.add( temp ) ;

But is there a short cut for this?

Comment: It depends on the signature of test.add, i.e. what arguments it expects. Assuming it test is a SomeClass and SomeClass::add(const SomeClassName&) then all you need is test.add(SomeClassName("stuff")). But it really depends on what you want to do, so maybe a fuller Java example, in a new question, would be better.

Answer (score 4):

Templates need to be declared **and** defined in the header.

Also: I don't think that is the real error. It mentions an instantiation of `ArrayList<std::string>` which I can't see anywhere.

[This FAQ entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12) explains why.

Comment: How do you declare a template in the header?  Isn't that just the template <class T> as I've done?

Comment: @elfsareus: Here `template` refers to the whole construct (e.g. `template<typename T> class Foo { };`). You need to give the definition of all member functions (or all functions in the case of template functions) in the same file as the declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put the templated code into a separate .cpp file... your constructor should be in the ArrayList header.  The point is that it's only when `main()` is compiled that the compiler realises it needs to instantiate ArrayList and what type T will take, and so it needs to have the code available to do the instantiation....