# "Undefined symbols" error in C++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I have `Point` class that has `X`, `Y` and `Name` as data members. I overloaded

```
T operator-(const Point<T> &);
```

This calculates the distance between two points and returns a value

```
template < typename T>
T Point<T>::operator-(const Point<T> &rhs)
{
cout << "\nThe distance between " << getName() << " and " 
<< rhs.getName() << " = ";

return sqrt(pow(rhs.getX() - getX(), 2) + pow(rhs.getY() - getY(), 2));;
}
```

The `main` function

```
int main () {

Point<double> P1(3.0, 4.1, "Point 1");

Point<double> P2(6.4, 2.9, "Point 2");

cout << P2 - P1;
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But the problem is that this program doesn't compile, and I receive this error:

```
Undefined symbols:
"Point<double>::operator-(Point<double>&)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Have you included the implementation of the operator in the header, or in a .cpp file?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes. I only have one .cpp file and it has the implementation.

Comment: Highly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can't compile non-specialized templates. You have to put the definition code in headers.

Comment: Templates can't be compiled as part of translation units by themselves. You need an instantiation or a specialization to compile them.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999358/undefined-symbols-linker-error-with-simple-template-class?rq=1
possible duplicates:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the?lq=1

Comment: I put the definition in .h file, and I still receive the same error!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your Point template class in a .hpp file and include that whenever using a Point.

Comment: I put the definition in .h file, and I still receive the same error!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include templates in each file that uses them, otherwise the compiler cannot generate the code for your specific type.

There is also a precedence between operators, which isn't changed when overloading them. Your code will be treated as

```
(cout << P2) - P1;
```

Try this instead

```
cout << (P2 - P1);
```